# Babel for of loop transpilation performance

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I use the `for of` loop often for readability and ease of writing code, but after transpiling with babel, i found it bloats up code and am now worried about performance.

**Here is what I mean**

**Input Code**

```js
const obj = {
  a: 2,
  bar: 'baz',
  identity: x => x
};

for (const [ key, val ] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key, val);
}
```

**Output Code**

```js
'use strict';

var _slicedToArray = function () { function sliceIterator(arr, i) { var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"]) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; } return function (arr, i) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { return arr; } else if (Symbol.iterator in Object(arr)) { return sliceIterator(arr, i); } else { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"); } }; }();

var obj = {
  a: 2,
  bar: 'baz',
  identity: function identity(x) {
    return x;
  }
};

var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
  for (var _iterator = Object.entries(obj)[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
    var _step$value = _slicedToArray(_step.value, 2),
        key = _step$value[0],
        val = _step$value[1];

    console.log(key, val);
  }
} catch (err) {
  _didIteratorError = true;
  _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
  try {
    if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
      _iterator.return();
    }
  } finally {
    if (_didIteratorError) {
      throw _iteratorError;
    }
  }
}
```

obviously, the transpiled `for of` loop has much more code...

But my question is, should i stop using the `for of` loop because of possible `"performance issues"` with transpiled code (babel using `iterators`, etc.. to do a simple loop), and if so, what should I use instead?

Comment: Why is babel necessary to use `for..of` loop?

Comment: Have you compared the performance to `Array` methods like `forEach`? That `for`–`of` loop could be rewritten as `Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => console.log(key, val));`.

Comment: @guest271314 Because [it’s been introduced in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: If you are using babel-preset-env you could change the behaviour to use the built-in functions. IE seems to be one of the only browsers
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: @Xufox `for..of` is supported by modern browsers according to the link

Comment: @guest271314 But not _all_ browsers. That’s the purpose of Babel: to make it work in all browsers.

Comment: @Xufox Are you referencing ie?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, for example.

Comment: @Xufox Why would any individual still be using ie unless they did not have another choice? See `// this is the equivalent of a for/of in ES6
var iterator = [1,2,3][Symbol.iterator]();
var result;
while (!(result = iterator.next()).done) {
  console.log(result.value); // 1 then 2 and then 3
}` at https://github.com/es-shims/get-own-property-symbols. There is also a polyfill for `Object.entries()` available https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries

Comment: I have polyfills, and am persistant in using `for of`. Not many browsers support the loop.

Comment: almost 5% of browsers are IE

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a generic 'should I stop using X because of possible performance issues?'

If X isn't causing performance issues now, and you don't have any evidence to show it'll cause performance issues in future, keep using it.

If it is or will cause performance issues, look for alternatives.

In this case of X being `for..of` then your alternatives are based on writing more code with the same behaviour.

Your example specifically iterates over an Object, so ignoring the fact `for..of` also supports iterating over sets and arrays, you only need to write slightly more code to iterate over the object properties:

```
for (const [ key, val ] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key, val);
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  const val = obj[key];
  console.log(key, val);
});

// You could also stick with a `for` loop (but note this isn't restricted to 
// the object's 'own' properties in the same way as values() and entries()
for (const key in obj) {
  const val = obj[key];
  console.log(key, val);
}
```

Comment: Sure.  I saw the word 'possible' without any links to evidence of actual performance issues, and also gave you suggestions of what to do if there really are performance issues: rewrite the code to ensure it's either transpiled to better performing code, or doesn't need transpiling at all.

Comment: I think I might be failing to grasp the point of your question now.  Should you stop using `for..of` because of performance worries?  Answer: No.

Comment: Runtime transpilation should be avoided, so the cost of transpilation is normally at build-time.  Babel plugins generally aim for correctness over performance, and no doubt miss optimisations you can do by hand.  However, unless and until you hit a performance problem, just enjoy the productivity boost of writing modern JS with babel :-)